# How to get all children blocks in controller Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers

I have to get all children block in controller using parent block name or layout Magento 2.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your controller is same which loads the layout in which your block and its child blocks exits.

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
  protected $resultPageFactory;

  public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       PageFactory $resultPageFactory
  ){
       $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
       parent::__construct($context);
  }

  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

  $blockInstance = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('your.block.name');

  $childBlocks = $blockInstance->getChildNames();

  foreach($childBlocks as $blockName){
    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
  }

}
```

Comment: saras amithsing nice answer.

Comment: It's working fine for me Thanks @ Amit Singh

Comment: @AmitSingh, Please explain, `$blockInstance->getChildNames();` here getChildNames() means?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all child blocks like this.

```
$allblocks = $block->getChildNames();

  foreach($allblocks as $blocks){
    $child_block = $this->resultPageFactory->create()->getLayout()->getBlock($blocks);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried all that function which is used to get child blocks  but it's not working.